# jQuery logical operator not working as expected

Tags: jquery, logical-operators

I have below code which is not working.

```
var book_id = $('#indexBookSearch');
var tag_id  = $('#indexTagSearch');

if((book_id.val() == "") || (tag_id.val() == ""))
{
    $('#userMessages').html('<div class="alert alert-info">'+
        '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;'+
        '</button>'+
        '<strong>Information ! </strong> Please select search criteria first.'+
    '</div>');
    return false;
}
```

`if((book_id.val() == "") || (tag_id.val() == ""))` this line is not working if even if either of the field has `value` inside of it.

Both `Book` and `Tag` is `select box` i have checked their value using `console.log()` and its coming perfectly.

**I have also changed**

```
if((book_id.val() == "") || (tag_id.val() == ""))
```

**to**

```
if(book_id.val() == "" || tag_id.val() == "")
```

**EDIT**

HTML FORM

```
<form id="indexSearchForm" action="books/listTags" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Search Criteria</legend>

        <label>Select Book</label>
        <select class="input-large" name="book_id" id="indexBookSearch">
            <option value="">--Select--</option>
            <option value="109">book 1</option>
        </select>

        <label>Select Tag</label>
        <select class="input-large" name="tag_id" id="indexTagSearch">
            <option value="">--Select--</option>
            <option value="10">adding</option>
            <option value="1">Apples</option>
            <option value="39">article</option>
            <option value="34">bhg</option>
            <option value="40">boon</option>
        </select>       
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

jQuery Code

```
$('#indexSearchForm').submit(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

    var book_id = $('#indexBookSearch');
    var tag_id  = $('#indexTagSearch');

    if( !book_id.val() || !tag_id.val())
    {
        $('#userMessages').html('<div class="alert alert-info">'+
            '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>'+
            '<strong>Information ! </strong> Please select search criteria first.'+
        '</div>');
        return false;
    }
    // more process
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the logic you are looking for? If either one is filled out, then you're ok? Or if both are not filled out, then there is a problem? Something else?

Comment: @Aiias i want to validate form to ask for user to fill in either of form fields..

Comment: Would be great if you put your HTML, I think that the "empty" option for your select box is something like " " instead of ""

Comment: @Aguardientico well if you forget to **read question**...i mentioned that i also checking it using `console.log()` and values are coming correctly..

Comment: what values are you getting in console.log? what are you putting on console.log?

Comment: @DipeshParmar Post your html code.

Comment: @DipeshParmar Did you use `$.trim()` function?

Comment: @Dipesh Parmar, use mine how I show....it will work

Comment: I have added HTML and jQuery code that i am using.

Comment: @DipeshParmar Your code is working condition. Check Fiddle Link : http://jsfiddle.net/B6ZFS/

Comment: @DipeshParmar - You should look into using jQuery's [`:selected`](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the === operator for strings...

```
if((book_id.val() === "") || (tag_id.val() === ""))
```

You could also do it like this...

```
if((book_id.val().charAt(0))||(tag_id.val().charAt(0)) {

//stuff if true - if either has a value
//Do whatever you want here, submit the form, navigate away, database...etc

} else {

//return error
$('#userMessages').html('<div class="alert alert-info">'+
    '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;'+
    '</button>'+
    '<strong>Information ! </strong> Please select search criteria first.'+
'</div>');
return false;

}
```

Like this...

Comment: Damn..You code worked but in different manner...now form is posting when two are blank and showing error when either or are filled with value....hahahaha

Comment: Yeah I know, you're supposed to put your code in the bottom else statement, the true stuff is for if they do enter something, so just switch the error to the bottom underneath else.....success goes above

Comment: Try again, put code in bottom half

Comment: WTF thats worked....strange but its worked... Very Very Strange..

Comment: Its checking for values not for emptiness....its working backwards how you expect

Comment: the only benefit to the other way, is you remove the need for an `else`.  IF it doesn't meet your criteria, throw the warning and return false.  otherwise, just keep executing the function.  Its easier to avoid nested If statements.

Comment: Well nothings stops him from doing a single if, and doing the success stuff and returning false.....same effect....then if false, the script just executes the rest....being the error display.  No need for else either.....I just used it to keep everything contained, matter of preference I guess

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
if( !book_id.val().length || !tag_id.val().length )
```

**edit**
Looking at it again, if neither are filled out, warn them - that's an and statement:

```
if( !book_id.val().length && !tag_id.val().length )
```

Comment: actually, I believe this should be `AND` not an `OR`.

Comment: well i said i want either or condition not `AND`..

Comment: was scrolled down, didnt see the edits to the original question...

Comment: But wait a minute! I see your logic behind that one.....it will work!

Comment: really, the edit in my would warn the user ONLY if BOTH fields were empty.  I believe that meets your criteria. If one is selected, that evaluates as false, if both are selected, again, false. - hah, false, being good? :]

Comment: Yeah thats perfect....so now... regardless, if they at least enter one thing, the error wont show, which is exactly what OP wants.....

Answer (score 0):

Try this with `empty`

```
if( empty(book_id.val()) || empty(tag_id.val()) )
```

or **BETTER** also can try with `.length` like

```
if ( (book_id.val().length != 0 ) || (tag_id.val().length != 0 ))
```

You can use `trim` for the removing the spaces can say trimming

Answer (score 0):

try to trim your value , it might contain value. Working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rajesh007/zFsFb/2/)

```
if ((book_id.val().trim() === "") || (tag_id.val().trim() === "")) {
    alert('true');
}
```